# Hide search provider from google search app?

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I have multiple search providers in my app. The thing with search providers is that they appear in the google search app/widget. Is there anyway to only display one of these providers instead of all of them? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you would bother having search providers that you do not want to have displayed.

That being said, you can disable their components via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. A disabled `ContentProvider` should not show up for the user to enable or in the actual search UI -- if it does, that'd be an Android bug IMHO. However, I do not know if re-enabling the provider will also require the user to go in and re-select it in the Search portion of the Settings app.

Comment: well i wan't them displayed in my app, but not by the google search app :)

Comment: @Richard: Then why are you using the search framework? Just create your own search field that triggers your own search code.

Comment: hum, maybe that's a better solution. Thanks anyhow :)